# правильный MySql запрос

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица `Товаров`. Таблица разделена на `id`,`name...`,`category`. Сейчас имею 5 категорий. При этом товаров примерно 380. Как одним запросом достать из БД по 50 товаров каждой категории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо пронумеровать строки в разрезе категорий и взять те, чьи номера меньше 50. В MySQL это можно сделать с помощью переменных, с запоминанием категории предыдущей строки при сортировке по категории. Если в итоге нужны какие то конкретные 50 записей, а не первые попавшиеся, то надо добавить соответствующие поля в сортировку.

```
select *
  from (
    select *,
           @num:=if(@grp=category, @num+1, 1) N,  -- Текущий номер строки равен
           -- Номеру из предыдущей +1, если категория совпадает с предыдущей строкой
           -- Или 1, если категория сменилась
           @grp:=category  -- Запоминаем текущую категорию
           -- (присвоение происходит после вычисления предыдущего поля, т.е. @num)
      from table_c,
           (select @num:=0, @grp:=NULL) x  -- Инициализируем переменные
     order by category
  ) X
 where N<=50
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но не работает

Comment: @TotalPusher Только что проверял, у меня работает. Собственно обязано работать на любой версии MySQL. P.S. поправил одно имя колонки потому что тестировался на таблице в которой не было колонки category

Comment: @Mike Не знаю что ты сделал но ты крут. Я не знал что MySql может быть таким не понятным. Надо подтянуться

Comment: @user8978194 Ну в MySQL нет кучи полезных возможностей, зато есть переменные, которые их заменяют. Есть единственная особенность, которая все и решает. Переменные, которые с собаками в начале помнят свое состояние, которое они получили  при обработке предыдущей строки выборки. Таким образом выборка представляется как обычный цикл, который построчно вычисляет значения переменных

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант:

```html
(SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `category` = 1 LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `category` = 2 LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `category` = 3 LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `category` = 4 LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM goods WHERE `category` = 5 LIMIT 50)
```

Если требуется более универсальное решение (f.e. заранее не известны номера категорий), то либо писать скрипт, либо создавать хранимую функцию, и обращаться к ней.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH s AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.category, 
    (SELECT id FROM product WHERE category = p.category ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 50) FROM product p)
SELECT * FROM product p
JOIN s ON s.category = p.category
WHERE p.id < s.id order by p.category;
```

PS По поводу валидности в MySql не уверен

Comment: это MySql? Или че то другое?

Comment: Этот запрос валиден для PSQL. Если в MySQL есть WITH, AS, LIMIT, OFFSET то должно быть все ок

Comment: В 8-ой версии добавили WITH, ранее можно эмулировать с помощью хранимой процедуры, см https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/22.html Кроме того в MySQL можно решить задачу с помощью пользовательских переменных.