# Помогите с группировкой в запросе

Tags: mysql

Нужно получить промежутки времени работы менеджеров, 15 минут бездействия считать за перерыв. И группировать их по менеджерам.
Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
  Managers.name, 
  manager_id, 
  work_period, 
  MIN(datetime) AS `start`, 
  MAX(datetime) AS `end`, 
  TIMEDIFF(
    MAX(datetime), 
    MIN(datetime)
  ) AS `result` 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      manager_id, 
      datetime, 
      @workperiod := @workperiod + if(
        datetime > @prev + interval 10 minute, 
        1, 0
      ) as work_period, 
      @prev := datetime 
    from 
      user_log, 
      (
        select 
          @prev := NULL, 
          @workperiod := 1
      ) X 
    order by 
      datetime
  ) A 
  INNER JOIN managers as Managers ON Managers.id = manager_id 
WHERE 
  datetime like '2019-01-18%' 
GROUP BY 
  work_period, 
  manager_id
```

Помогите пожалуйста переделать так, что бы этот фрагмент, считался с учетом manager_id. Сейчас проверка интервала идет с предыдущей записью не учитывая менеджера.

```
@workperiod := @workperiod + if(
    datetime > @prev + interval 10 minute, 
    1, 0
  ) as work_period
```

На скриншоте структура таблицы:

[image: структура таблицы]

Comment: Запоминание менеджера и его учет возьмите отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/823206/194569 не забудьте добавить менеджера в сортировку на первое место

Comment: @Mike, Посмотрите пожалуйста, так ли вы имели введу
`@workperiod := if(
        @manager=manager_id,
            @workperiod + if(
                datetime > @prev + interval 10 minute, 
                1, 0
            ),
        1
        ) as work_period, `
предварительно определив @manager := NULL
и далее перезаписав его

Comment: Ну и дополнить 
`order by 
      manager_id,
      datetime`

Comment: только в этом if начальное значение для нового менеджера вам "1" подходит ?

Comment: @Mike, Начальное значение менеджера установил NULL:
`select 
@manager := NULL,
@prev := NULL, 
@workperiod := 1`
после - переопределяю его 
`@manager := manager_id`
А в условии назначаю `@workperiod` "1", если начался новый менеджер.

Comment: @Mike, Сейчас проверил, работает. Спасибо большое